# Remove message and load it from an external json file

Tags: json, nativescript

I am new to Nativescript. I created a new project and I am trying to edit the template that came with it. I want to remove the message "Hoorraaay! You..." and load it from an external json file.

**This is the code:main-view-model.js**

```
var Observable = require("data/observable").Observable;
function getMessage(counter) {
if (counter <= 0) {
    return "Hoorraaay! You unlocked the NativeScript clicker achievement!";
} else {
    return counter + " taps left";
}

}
function createViewModel() {
var viewModel = new Observable();
viewModel.counter = 5;
viewModel.message = getMessage(viewModel.counter);

viewModel.onTap = function() {
    this.counter--;
    this.set("message", getMessage(this.counter));
}

return viewModel;
}
exports.createViewModel = createViewModel;
```

**This is my JSON File: config.json**

```
{
"Message"   : "Hoorraaay! You unlocked the NativeScript clicker achievement! Congratulations!"
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
var configJson = require("./config.json");
```

PlayGround demo demonstrating the above in JavaScript project can be found [here](https://play.nativescript.org/?template=play-js&id=6lIrPd)

Comment: @Nick Illiev 
 
Hey Nick, could you please let me know how to connect two json files to home-view-model.js? I have one json file with chart properties and another json file with chart data. I want the .js file to load both of this json files and display the chart. Thanks in advance

Comment: LSA here is an example of using two separate JSON files and settings them as a source and as properties in your observable model https://play.nativescript.org/?template=play-js&id=iJYHYc

Comment: @NickIliev BTw why didn't you suggest the file-sytem library in order to read the local file ? behind the scenes it uses `java.io.File`. so I guess that the question is what's the diff as opposed to `require` ?